# Error bars in ggplot2 stat_summary_bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to average time series data across 10 bins and plot a bin averaged plot.

Using `ggplot2`, how could I overlay error bars with `stat_summary_bin()` ?

Here is what I have tried:

```
# My data
load("xyz.Rdata")

str(df)
# data.frame':  125 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ xdata : num  -0.0209 -0.04 1.4145 0.7419 0.9393 ...
# $ ydata : num  -19.78 -23.29 8.86 16.04 11.65 ...
# $ ir.fac: Factor w/ 3 levels "irh","irl","irm": 2 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 2 ...

# Graph
ggplot(df) + 
stat_summary_bin(aes(x = xdata, y = ydata, color= ir.fac),
                 fun.y = "mean",
                 bins= 10, size= 0.5, 
                 geom= 'line') +
stat_summary_bin(aes(x = xdata, y = ydata, color = ir.fac),
                 fun.y = "mean",
                 bins= 10, size= 2, 
                 geom= "point")
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, so that we can run your code.

Comment: Does `fun.data=mean_se` give the output you're looking for?

Comment: No,  data= mean_se throws up an error.

Comment: fun.data, not data. Use that on the second call to stat_summary_bin, and remove geom="point".

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I've added an answer. Please let me know if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the built-in `iris` data frame. `fun.data=mean_se` gives a point with an error bar equal to +/- 1 standard error by default. To change this to, say, 1.96 standard errors, add the argument `fun.args=list(mult=1.96)` to `stat_summary_bin`.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

pd=position_dodge(0.07)

ggplot(iris) + 
  stat_summary_bin(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color= Species),
                   fun.y = "mean", position=pd,
                   bins= 10, size=0.8, 
                   geom= "line") +
  stat_summary_bin(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color= Species),
                   fun.data = mean_se, position=pd,
                   bins= 10, size= 0.4)
```

[image]

If you want a bootstrapped confidence interval instead of a classical standard error, you can use `fun.data=mean_cl_boot` instead of `fun.data=mean_se`, which will give a 95% CI by default.

Comment: Thanks eipi10, help appreciated

Comment: Hi, curious to know why applied ran position_dodge to this plot?

Comment: In case the error bars for different Species overlap (which happens in only one case here) you need slight dodging in order to see where each error bar ends.